# Error:No such property: GROUP for class: org.gradle.api.publication.maven.internal.ant.DefaultGroovyMavenDeployer

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, import-module

I want to use [RecyclerViewLib](https://github.com/twotoasters/RecyclerViewLib) in my project and for that I downloaded it and imported it as a module to my empty "hello world" Android project. I am using android studio v1.0.1 using sdk manager v24 and this is my app/build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 17
buildToolsVersion "19.1.0"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.mk.dragdrop4"
    minSdkVersion 14
    targetSdkVersion 17
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
}
```

and this is my library/build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 17
    buildToolsVersion "19.1.0"

    defaultConfig {

        minSdkVersion 7
        targetSdkVersion 17
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:20.0.0'
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
}

apply from: 'https://raw.github.com/twotoasters/gradle-mvn-push/master/gradle-mvn-push.gradle'
```

But when I import that I'm getting this error message:

```
 Error:No such property: GROUP for class: org.gradle.api.publication.maven.internal.ant.DefaultGroovyMavenDeployer
```

Can anyone help me about this problem?

Answer (score 284, accepted):

Remove this line from the build.gradle on the specified project

```
apply from: 'https://raw.github.com/twotoasters/gradle-mvn-push/master/gradle-mvn-push.gradle'
```

Comment: hi @goonerdroid that's work thank you. but can you explain more about this line and what exactly do ?

Comment: library has gradle tasks for uploading to the Maven repository that require some properties to be set for the gradle environment, in your project you don't need/want that.

Answer (score 47):

I have experienced a very similar problem.

I tried to include the QuickReturn feature into my app : https://github.com/felipecsl/QuickReturn

I'm using Android Studios 1.0 and after I imported the library into my project, it gives me the same error. I then looked at the build.gradle file for the library and removed this line and it worked:

```
apply from: 'gradle-mvn-push.gradle'
```

Comment: The project or the module that you just imported. It has a gradle file too. This line can be found in that gradle file. Just follow @Simon's advice and you are good to go. Thanx simon.

Comment: Is this the only solution?

Answer (score 14):

Similar issue.

Removed line:

```
apply from: 'maven-push.gradle'
```

from build.gradle and was able to sync successfully.

Comment: Doing this worked for me. What are the consequences of not having this statement?

Comment: I don't see this line in any of my build.gradle files. What should I do?

Answer (score 2):

check library and project build.gradle and comment this line if you found

`apply from: 'https://raw.github.com/chrisbanes/gradle-mvn-push/master/gradle-mvn-push.gradle'`

Answer (score 0):

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3'  // include latest gradle version and if project build with older version can update or can user same version

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
```