# Error:No such property: GROUP for class: org.gradle.api.publication.maven.internal.ant.DefaultGroovyMavenDeployer on Import

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

Hi I want to use bar graph in my app. So I imported [this](https://github.com/blackfizz/EazeGraph) project from Github. While importing I get the error

Error:No such property: GROUP for class: org.gradle.api.publication.maven.internal.ant.DefaultGroovyMavenDeployer

I am using Android Studio 1.5.1

my app/build.gradle file is

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

    signingConfigs {
        release {
            storeFile file(STORE_FILE)
            storePassword STORE_PASSWORD
            keyAlias KEY_ALIAS
            keyPassword KEY_PASSWORD
        }
    }

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "org.eazegraph.app"
        minSdkVersion 9
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }

    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'

            signingConfig signingConfigs.release

            // this is used to alter output directory and file name. If you don't need it
            // you can safely comment it out.
            applicationVariants.all { variant ->
                variant.outputs.each { output ->
                    def file = output.outputFile

                    String parent = file.parent
                    if (project.hasProperty('OUTPUT_DIR') && new File((String) OUTPUT_DIR).exists())
                        parent = OUTPUT_DIR

                    output.outputFile = new File(
                            parent,
                            (String) file.name.replace(
                                    ".apk",

                                    // alter this string to change output file name
                                    "-" + defaultConfig.versionName + "-build" + defaultConfig.versionCode + ".apk"
                            )
                    )
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile project(':EazeGraphLibrary')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
}
```

my project/build.gradle is

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.0.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
```

Can anyone please help me.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: set `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.2.3'`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28450549/errorno-such-property-group-for-class-org-gradle-api-publication-maven-intern?rq=1

Comment: you can set `compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"` & `targetSdkVersion 23`