# What to do as AndroidSlidingUpPanel Library is using some libraries not up to date

Tags: java, android

I was trying to use **AndroidSlidingUpPanel** in my app but when I was trying to build the Gradle file is giving me this warning.

```
All com.android.support libraries must use the exact same version specification (mixing versions can lead to runtime crashes). Found versions 26.0.0-alpha1, 23.4.0. Examples include com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:26.0.0-alpha1 and com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.4.0 more...
```

I have seen the files in GitHub and saw that the file *AndroidSlidingUpPanel/library/build.gradle* is using a lower version of :

1. compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.4.0'
2. compile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:23.4.0'
3. compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.4.0'

which should be something like this:

1. compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.+'
2. compile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:26.+'
3. compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.+'

When I downloaded the library and imported it as module it was giving error too:

```
Error:(21, 0) Could not read script             
'I:\ANDROID\Android_Studio_Projects\TRYS\Theme3\maven_push.gradle' as it 
does not exist.
<ahref="openFile:I:\ANDROID\Android_Studio_Projects\TRYS\Theme3\library\build.gradle">Open File</a>
```

Even after copying **maven_push.gradle** to root it is giving this error:`Error:Could not get unknown property 'GROUP' for object of type org.gradle.api.publication.maven.internal.deployer.DefaultGroovyMavenDeployer.`

So what to do?

Comment: There are some duplicates: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42374151/all-com-android-support-libraries-must-use-the-exact-same-version-specification

Comment: Yes, I tried those steps but the problem is in Gradle file of the library and I am mot able to find it in the project structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

open android studio and get to this page
[image]

press this part 
[image]

it will open a drop-down menu press git and then [image]

press clone and your done

Comment: When I am cloning it is giving me **Clone Failed** Failed to start Git Process .

Comment: When I am  testing the ink it is giving Repository test has failed

Answer (score 0):

You have two options

1. Post an issue in the library on GitHub and wait for the creator to update.
2. Add it to your project manually by pulling​ the project from git and update the libraries your self.

Comment: Yes, I tried to do so but it is giving me some trouble as I have already told in the question(as per point 2 in your answer).

Comment: Did you created a new project from Android Studio and pulled the files or just downloaded from GitHub as zip and tried to open it?

Comment: No I downloaded the library as a zip and extracted it. Then created a new android project named "MyNewApp" and then I went to File>New>Import Module and then I browsed for the directory of the library and clicked finish.

Comment: Use method 2 and get the project by pulling from git

Comment: Can you please tell me the steps

Comment: i have uploaded a new answer with images to explain you the process

Answer (score 0):

Remove lines referring to  maven_push.gradle from the build.gradle on the specified project.

Example:

```
apply from: 'https://raw.github.com/chrisbanes/gradle-mvn-push/master/gradle-mvn-push.gradle'

apply from: './mvn-push.gradle'
```

Just comment them out. I've got this solution after going through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28450634/1911652)